# Prove that every word in a free group has a unique representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $F(X)$ be a free group on the set $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. I want to show that every $w \in F(X)$ has a unique representation $w=x_{1}^{e^1}x_{2}^{e^2}...x_{n}^{e^n}c$ for some $e_{1},...,e_{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $c\in [F(X),F(X)]$.

Here is my reasoning so far:

a word $w \in F(X)$ has the form $w=(x_{1}^{e_{1}^1}x_{2}^{e_{1}^2}...x_{n}^{e_{2}^n})(x_{1}^{e_{2}^1}x_{2}^{e_{2}^2}...x_{n}^{e_{1}^n})...(x_{1}^{e_{m}^1}x_{2}^{e_{m}^2}...x_{n}^{e_{m}^n})$, and if $w$ contains a subword $u \in [F(X),F(X)]$, we can somehow move it all the way to the right.

Basically I claim that I can represent the word $w$ uniquely where each $e^{i}=e_{1}^{i}+e_{2}^{i}+...+e_{m}^{i}$ minus the ones in $[F(X),F(X)]$, and $c$ is the product of all subwords of $w$ in $[F(X),F(X)]$.

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: If you meant "element" instead of "word" in the first line then it isn't true **unless** you require some kind of *normal* form (or normal reduced form) for the words (if you meant "word" in the first line then there is nothing to prove...), otherwise $\;x_1=x_1x_2x_2^{-1}\;$ , for example

Comment: Yes I meant to type reduced word.

Comment: It follows from the fact that $G/[G,G] \cong {\mathbb Z}^n$, where the direct factors are generated by the images of the $x_i$.

Comment: Are you using the fact that there is a unique epimomorphism $\phi:F \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $ker(\phi)=[F,F]$? The image of each $x_i \in X$ is $x_{i}\phi = (0,...0,1,0,...0) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ where the "1" is in the ith position?

Comment: Sorry I still don't quite understand. Clearly $\phi$ is not injective, so how can you possibly give an element in $F$ a unique representation based on its image?

Comment: You have a subgroup $[F,F] = \ker \phi$ and a set of coset representatives $x_1^{e_1} \cdots x_n^{e_n}$. Every element has a unique representations as coset rep $\times$ element of subgroup, and $c$ is your subgroup element.

Comment: Are you saying each $w \in F$ can be uniquely written as $w=w_{1}u_{1}...w_{k}u_{k}$ such that each $u_i \in [F,F]$ and each $w_i \notin [F,F]$?

Comment: No, where did you get that from?

Comment: I see, the uniqueness of $w$ comes from $c \in [F(X),F(X)]$.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you have such an representation. Just let $w$ be any word in $X$ in which $x_n$ occurs only once at first place. Then $c$ an be any word in $\{x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}\}$, since $c$ has no $x_n$ you can replace $x_n$ in the commutator by any $x_i$. That would mean $F(X)=[F(X),F(X)]$ which is not the case since the abelianization of the free group on $X$ is the free abelian group on $X$.

You could prove instead that the length of two words $a,b$ adds if the last character of first word $a$ is not equal to the the inverse of the first character second word $b$.

Then assume $a=b$. So multiplying by the inverse gives a word of length zero. Hence both words $a$ and $b$ must have the same last character.

Now you could do an induction on the length of the words.

For $n=1$ this is clear. So assume 
$x=y$, then $x = x'z = y' z$ but $x'=y'$ have same representation by induction hypothesis.